# AndroidのPUSH通知の色についてお聞きしたいです

Tags: android

androidの通知のカラーに白（透明）、グレー、黒のアイコンを設定したいのですが
こちら可能であるかが知りたいです、、

いくつか試したり検索をかけて調べたのですが単色しか出来ないという信頼できる記事がなく投稿しました
対象となるアイコンでない場合アイコン自体が白くなることは把握しましたが、なんとかして実現できないかと考えています。

ご存知の方がおりましたらご教授いただきたく思います

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar によれば、Android3.0以降では「ステータスバーのアイコンは、透明な背景に白いピクセルだけで構成され、アルファブレンディングはスムーズなエッジに使用され、内部のテクスチャは適切な場合に使用され」るそうです。
上記は、下記原文のGoogle翻訳です。

> Status bar icons are composed simply of white pixels on a transparent
>   backdrop, with alpha blending used for smooth edges and internal
>   texture where appropriate.

単色というか白だけってことですね。